# Document upload extension validation in JavaScript not working

Tags: javascript, html, validation

**While trying validation in JS for my HTML code, the file upload validation is not working.
It shows an alert to upload the document but when i upload it, it still pops alert and it's not working.**
Below is my JS Validation code.

```
var Document =document.getElementById("docs").value;
var filePath = Document.value;
var allowedExtensions =/(\.doc|\.docx|\.odt|\.pdf|\.tex|\.txt|\.rtf|\.wps|\.wks|\.wpd)$/i;

if (allowedExtensions.test(filePath))
    { 
        return true;  
    }  
    else{
        alert("Please upload a file");
        return false;
    }
```

Below is my HTML code.

```
<label>Document: </label>
<input type="file" id="docs">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `filePath` (`Document.value`) is always `undefined`. You need to remove one of the 2 `.value` in the 2 first lines

Comment: Thank You, it's working now. Moreover it is to be mentioned "return false" in the else section.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it may help other. What is the point of `return false` outside a function ?